# error <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, declare-styleable

I had update my eclipse Version: 4.2.2 and android SDK with API 23.
When i created an app then get an error like this.

> [2015-10-12 17:03:05 - appcompat_v7] ERROR: In  MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing

and warning

> [2015-10-12 16:50:14 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file D:\lolipop Workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  R.java  /appcompat_v7/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat  line 3065   Java Problem
```

[image]
please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck? I am getting this.  I've tried everything. Removing libraries etc

Comment: @AndroidKen when i create new workspace then i got there no issue like this you can try this trick hope it work for you........

Answer (score 4):

check your appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml file

and find "android:preserveIconSpacing" in file

and freeze it.
and run app.

it's work for me.