# Error:In <declare-styleable> - unable to find attribute

Tags: android, gradle, attributes

I'm getting Gradle errors for missing attributes when trying to build my project;

`Error:In <declare-styleable> ReflowText, unable to find attribute maxDuration`

and

`Error:In <declare-styleable> ReflowText, unable to find attribute velocity`

I've just attempted to implement [`ReflowText`](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/transitions/ReflowText.java) in my project. The `ReflowText` class has been copy & pasted from the above link with no changes (except for package name) and I have copied the associated required attributes;

[**`res/values/attrs_reflow_text.xml`**](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/attrs_reflow_text.xml)

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="ReflowText">
        <attr name="velocity" />
        <attr name="minDuration" />
        <attr name="maxDuration" />
        <attr name="staggerDelay" format="integer" />
        <attr name="freezeFrame" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

I cannot work out why I am getting a build error. I have looked at various other SO questions with similar errors but none of the answers on them seem to address my issue;

- [ERROR: In  MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248579/error-in-declare-styleable-menuview-unable-to-find-attribute-androidpreserv)
- [error  MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081854/error-declare-styleable-menuview-unable-to-find-attribute-androidpreserveico)
- [Error:In  SherlockSpinner, unable to find attribute android:popupPromptView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726125/errorin-declare-styleable-sherlockspinner-unable-to-find-attribute-androidp)

My full Gradle Console output is;

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingAdapters131Library
:app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingLibrary131Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72510Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout100Beta4Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2510Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2511Library
:app:prepareComBignerdranchAndroidExpandablerecyclerview300RC1Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4180Library
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUi111Library
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUiAuth111Library
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUiDatabase111Library
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUiStorage111Library
:app:prepareComGithubClansFab164Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon1001Library
:app:prepareComJakewhartonButterknife851Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetComposer230Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetUi230Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitter230Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore230Library
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1314Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Android\traffitool\app\google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> ReflowText, unable to find attribute maxDuration
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> ReflowText, unable to find attribute minDuration
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> ReflowText, unable to find attribute velocity


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:201)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:867)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:194)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package io.traffitool -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:865)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package io.traffitool -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Android\traffitool\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
    ... 9 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.096 secs
```

Comment: so whats the format of `velocity`, `minDuration` and `maxDuration`?

Comment: @pskink `int` which are defined in the `ReflowText` class. I didn't feel the need to add them into the `attrs` file as the code is copy/pasted from a working example (using the if its not broken, don't fix it mantra - although clearly mine is broken)

Comment: but they are not defined in your project, thats why you are getting `ERROR: In <declare-styleable> ReflowText, unable to find attribute velocity`

Answer (score 0):

The `<attr>` tag require two attributes: `name` and `format`.

It is not well documented in developer.android.com, but you can get a small vision of that in [developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr).

You need a full attribution for `velocity`, `minDuration` and `maxDuration`:

```
    ...
    <attr name="velocity" format="integer" />
    <attr name="minDuration" format="integer" />
    <attr name="maxDuration" format="integer" />
    ...
```

Check whether `integer` is the format what you need. Other valid values are `float`, `string`, `boolean`, `color`, `dimension`, `fraction`, `enum`, `flag` and `reference`.